# Пхеньян, Пхьончхан чи Пйончанг

Tags: фонетика, іншомовні-слова, transliteration

На просторах інтернету трапляється написання столиці Північної Кореї у трьох варіантах [Пхеньян](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/news-40872518), [Пхьончхан](https://24tv.ua/sanktsiyi_pochali_kusatis_ekspert_poyasniv_chomu_kndr_pogodilas_na_peregovori_zi_ssha_n931865) і [Пьончанг](https://vn.depo.ua/ukr/vn/2017/cherez-vinnichchinu-proyidut-uchasniki-mizhnarodnogo-velokaravanu-20170720608817), а на Вікіпедії є [обговорення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%9F%D1%85%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD_%E2%86%92_%D0%9F%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3) щодо написання Пйончанг. Який із варіантів є найбільш прийнятним в українській мові?

Answer (score 5):

Вочевидь, мова йде про два різні міста [Пхеньян](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD) та [Пхьончхан](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%85%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD).
Для передачі корейських назв кирилицею нині використовується [Система Концевича](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0), яка фактично створювалась для російської мови.

Comment: Факти й уточнення, що ви їх тут навели, дуже цінні. Разом з тим, було б добре, якби ви доповнили вашу відповідь і пояснили, як, все-таки, правильно писати назву столиці Півд. Кореї кирилицею, адже в питанні були не тільки Пхеньян та Пхьончхан, а ще й Пьончанг. Отже, ідеальна відповідь виглядала б так: 1. Те, що вже є. 2. Те, як треба писати назву столиці кирилицею відповідно до Системи Концевича. 3. За вашим бажанням, можна ще висловити свою думку, якщо вона відрізняється від системи Концевича (тоді буде варіант для офіційного вжитку і для особистого). Дякую за внесок.

Answer (score 0):

Як вже [зазначено](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4588/585), тут два міста і наразї вживаною транслітерацією є московська система Концевича. То загальна проблєма для азійських мов, лише не так давно просунули ся в питаннї китайської, а для японської зазвичай вживають близшу, бо поєднали подібну структуру приголосних анґлійської і просту схему голосних, але однаково чужу — анґлійську систему Гепберна.

За вимовою то відповідно i приблизно:

- 평창 — pʰʲʌŋ.t͡ɕʰaŋ
- 평양 — pʰʲʌŋ.jaŋ

За московською системою:

- 평창 — *Пхьончхан*
- 평양 — **Пхьонʼян**, походження *Пхеньян* не дуже зрозуміле:

  - **ья** замість **ъя**, схоже на вплив нових записів як *компьютер*, *верфю* ітд; за [українським правописом](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=131) чужомовні сполуки як **нʼя** теж будуть записані як **нья**, тому скорїш за всього, теж мати ймемо **Пхьоньян**.
  - **е** — не дуже зрозуміло відки. Припускаю, геть старий усталений запис, як і назви *Токіо*, *Кіото* в японській, котрі теж суперечать усталеним транскрипціям, де мусило бути приблизно як *Токјо* і *Кјото*, де замість **ј** — відповідно **й** чи **ь**, що залеже від самої транскрипції.

Тому якщо брати звичай українського правописа, котрому насаджували московські правила і відтоді мало чого виправили, то скоріш за всього так і буде: **Пхьончхан**, **Пхеньян**, хоч і перший склад однаковий. Не дивуйте ся, вже маємо подібну проблєму з *орто-* і *орфо-* з грецької, котру трохи унормували лише в (коли затвердили) [2019 роцї](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_2019_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1993_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83).

Додатково. Анґлійська теж має подібну дивину: усталені *Pyeongchang* і *Pyongyang*, але за тзв [новою системою](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) там *Pyeongchang* і *Pyeongyang* відповідно.

---

Про суто українських систем я поки не чув, тому спробуємо *грубо* і *коротко* зробити льокальну саме для цих слів.

- ŋ — відоміший для нас як анґлійський звук **ng**, котрого особисто зазвичай раджу передавати як **нь**. Якщо треба буде умовно ставити 뇨 **nyo** проти ㅇ오 ***ngʼo**, то другого записуємо як **ньʼо**. Замість апострофа можна вжити і дефіс. А для ㄴ залишити **н**.
- t͡ɕ — вже знайомий з японської чи польської, там **ч(ь)**. Оскільки тут умовно можуть бути додаткові помʼякшення, тобто **cho** проти **chyo**, то просто **ч**.
- ʌ — зазвичай позначають як **о**. А ㅗ можна записувати, якщо треба виокремити, як **о́**.
- ʰ — традиційно ніяк не записують. Нам повезло, же корейська не має дзвінких — лише як алофони, отже можемо пристосувати китайську схему: придихові — глухі, непридихові — дзвінкі.
- ʲ — звична мʼякість. Зауважу, же українські губні і ґрупа «заднїх» приголосних зазвичай тверді.

Тому буде десь 평창 **Пйоньчань** і 평양 **Пйоньянь**.